# Why do I get CancelledKeyException when going through the keys?

Tags: java, exception, networking, nio

Why do I get the `CancelledKeyException` few times a day? Should I do something about it? Is my code wrong?

```
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {

            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();
            keys.remove();

            try {
                if (key.isValid()) {
                    if (key.isReadable()) {
                        readHandler.handle((Connection) key.attachment());
                    }
                    if (key.isWritable()) {
                        writeHandler.handle((Connection) key.attachment());
                    }
                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        acceptHandler.handle(key);
                    }
                }
            } catch (CancelledKeyException e) {
                _logger.error("CanceledKeyException in while loop:", e);
            }
        }
```

Exception:

```
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.readyOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:69) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.isWritable(SelectionKey.java:294) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at project.engine.io.SimpleReactor.work(SimpleReactor.java:194) ~[engine-02.06.11.jar:na]
    at project.server.work.AbstractWorker$1.run(AbstractWorker.java:20) [server-21.05.11.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [na:1.6.0_12]
```

Comment: What does the exception state? Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: @the-elite-gentleman, hmm, there is no stacktrace, but just this when i log the `e`: `java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException`.. Weird.

Comment: Huh? If an exception is thrown it should always include a stacktrace as well. That's inherited by throwable so I don't see how that should be possible.

Comment: @voo, oops. I logged it incorrectly. When will get it will post the stack trace.

Comment: @the-elite-gentleman, any idea about the exception?

Comment: Answers should not be part of questions, so I rolled back to the previous revision. (Please correct me if this is wrong)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the handlers may close the channel. For example, the read handler *should* close the channel if it reads a -1. So the write handler will then fail. Indeed `isWritable()` will fail, as I can now see from your stack trace. So you must test `isValid()` with every other condition, e.g. `isValid() && isReadable(),` `isValid() && isWritable(),` etc.

Comment: Ohh, should I also leave the `isValid()` like i have now before all the `isReadable()` etc. and just add the `isValid()` to each `isReadable()` as you said? Or it isn't needed to leave the `isValid()` one I have now?

Comment: @Richards what you have now isn't adequate. Otherwise you wouldn't be posting here. Change it.

Comment: @Richards: change it to what I said above. I even gave you the code.

Answer (score 0):

EJP's solution doesn't seem to be the ideal one... I think the correct way to handle a selection key that was canceled in the middle of the selector loop is to surround it with a try/catch and check for a `CancelledKeyException`, as in:

```
try {
   if (key.isReadable())
      processMessage(key);

   if (key.isAcceptable())
      acceptConnection(key);
}
catch (CancelledKeyException e) {
   logger.debug("Key cancelled... Closing channel.");
   key.channel().close();
}
```

Comment: Not ideal by what criterion exactly?

Comment: Because I don't think it solves the problem. The problem is that the key is cancelled *after* the call to key.isValid() and *before* the `isWritable()` / `isReadable()` / `isAcceptable()` call. I don't see much difference between OP's code and what you suggested. The only difference is that you check if the key is valid three times, whereas OP checks just once for each iteration of the loop. Your solution may work probably because you give less time for this concurrency issue to manifest. But it's still there, not solved.

Comment: There is only a concurrency issue if there are multiple threads, which don't appear anywhere in the OP, and which isn't normally the case with NIO, the point of it being to eliminate threads.

Comment: Well, that depends on how NIO is implemented internally. Are you positive it doesn't use/rely on multiple threads, in any architecture? Nevertheless, the concurrency I'm talking about is between the local machine and the remote ones. They are executing at the same time. For instance, the remote host may disconnect right after OP's call to `isValid()`, and the corresponding key is cancelled just before he tries to access that key. That's why calling `key.isValid()` before each access may work sometimes. Do you see any other explanation for that?

Comment: There are no internal threads in NIO. It only uses the threads you use yourself. The remote host disconnecting doesn't cancel the key. Only the local application can do that. The remote disconnect actually causes the key to become readable, with a pending end-of-stream to be read.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the thread doing the cancel is a different one than the one which registers the channel for selection. It seems this exception happens when the key is being cancelled first and next the other thread is registering the key again without a select in between. So I solved it by just doing a dummy select just prior to registering the channel again for select. It seems some bookkeeping is done in the select which is neccessary for the registration action to be succesful.
Both threads  use synchronized blocks (3 in total) on a shared static object to lock the registration, cancel and select action respectively.

Comment: Testing this further it appeared that doing a select an not handling the selected keys is fatal. When I say 'dummy select' I mean a select with a 1L timeout for which the selected keys are handled like the other thread does.